# Customized Moving Average on Pandas Dataframe With GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, moving-average

There is a dataset with columns `ID` and `Feature_1`. `Feature_1` could be understood as a specific duration of session in secs. There is also a custom function, which calculates moving average with addition of simple average in the begining according to number of NaN's caused by window width. Here it is:

```
def moving_average_mit_anfang(x, w):
        # First part - simple average
        first_part_result = np.cumsum(x)/np.cumsum(np.ones(len(x)))
        # If appearence of user's sessions is greater than window width, we calculate moving average
        if len(x)>w:
            # Second part - moving average with window w
            sec_part_result = np.convolve(x, np.ones(w), 'valid') / w
            return np.append(first_part_result[:-len(sec_part_result)],sec_part_result)
        # Otherwise we calculate only simple average
        else:
            return first_part_result
```

We should apply this function on column `Featrue_1` in such way, that we get current average  value for each ID, according to appearence time of corresponding ID.

Example dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[1,2,3,2,3,1,2,1,3,3,3,2,1],
                   'Feature_1':[4,5,6,73,2,21,13,45,32,9,18,45,39]})
```

I tried this:

```
test_df.groupby('ID')['Feature_1'].transform(lambda x: moving_average_mit_anfang(x,1))
```

And got this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-6cc3e6c9b134> in <module>
----> 1 test_df.groupby('ID')['Feature_1'].transform(lambda x: moving_average_mit_anfang(x,1))

~/DS/RS/rs_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in transform(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    505 
    506         if not isinstance(func, str):
--> 507             return self._transform_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
    508 
    509         elif func not in base.transform_kernel_allowlist:

~/DS/RS/rs_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _transform_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    535                 res = res._values
    536 
--> 537             results.append(klass(res, index=group.index))
    538 
    539         # check for empty "results" to avoid concat ValueError

~/DS/RS/rs_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    346                 try:
    347                     if len(index) != len(data):
--> 348                         raise ValueError(
    349                             f"Length of passed values is {len(data)}, "
    350                             f"index implies {len(index)}."

ValueError: Length of passed values is 6, index implies 4.
```

Output should be like:

```
    ID  Feature_1  Custom average
0    1          4             4.0
1    2          5             5.0
2    3          6             6.0
3    2         73            39.0
4    3          2             4.0
5    1         21            12.5
6    2         13            43.0
7    1         45            33.0
8    3         32             4.0
9    3          9            20.5
10   3         18            13.5
11   2         45            29.0
12   1         39            42.0
```

Comment: How should looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new solution working, also is possible omit lambda function for simplier solution (with lambda working too):

```
test_df['Custom average'] = test_df.groupby('ID')['Feature_1'].transform(moving_average_mit_anfang,2)
print (test_df)
    ID  Feature_1  Custom average
0    1          4             4.0
1    2          5             5.0
2    3          6             6.0
3    2         73            39.0
4    3          2             4.0
5    1         21            12.5
6    2         13            43.0
7    1         45            33.0
8    3         32            17.0
9    3          9            20.5
10   3         18            13.5
11   2         45            29.0
12   1         39            42.0
```

Comment: Almost! It gives that:

  
`ID
1                   [4.0, 12.5, 4.0, 21.0, 45.0, 39.0]
2                   [5.0, 39.0, 5.0, 73.0, 13.0, 45.0]
3    [6.0, 4.0, 13.333333333333334, 6.0, 2.0, 32.0,...`    

Now, I need to un-groupby it on the initial dataframe

Comment: `Now, I need to un-groupby it on the initial dataframe` - what it means? Because ouput has lengths of arrays greater like groups of original DataFrame

Comment: @StepanSokol - Can you edit question, because bad format it comments, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. 
As you see, I need to get specific for ID current value of moving average at every separate index

Comment: @StepanSokol - Sure, so need filter ouput if there is multiple values?

Comment: Something is wrong. The function `moving_average_mit_anfang` itself returns the same length of array, it got as an argument. So the width of window should be simply tunable and I got an error

Comment: @StepanSokol - `The function moving_average_mit_anfang itself returns the same length of array,` - Unfortuantely not. For ID=1,2 return 6 values, for `ID=3` return 8 values

Comment: Fixed. Updated in question

Comment: @StepanSokol - hmm, so your solution now working, but return no expected ouput, numbers are different.

Comment: I will check it. Function merges the simple and moving average. On large datasets this border won't be too crucial

Comment: how does it works by you, without slice `[:len(x)]` ?

Comment: @StepanSokol - yop, added to answer.